# Search block of text, return MP3 links using PHP

Tags: php, regex, mp3, html-parsing

I've just run into a little bit of trouble with some PHP on my latest project. Basically I have a block of text (`$text`) and I would like to search through that text and return all of the MP3 links. I know it has something to do with regular expressions but I just cannot get it working.

Here's my current code:

```
    if(preg_match_all(".mp3", $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {

  foreach($matches as $match) {
   echo $match[2];
   echo $text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Once again, regex is extremely poor at parsing HTML. Use a proper HTML parser to scrape information out of a web page.

For example, use [`DOMDocument::loadHTML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to parse the HTML content, then [`getElementsByTagName('a')`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) to get a list of links in the page. For each link, `getAttribute('href')` to see where it points.

Note however that there is absolutely no guarantee that MP3 files will always and only be stored under filenames ending in `.mp3`. On the web, the type of a resource does not have to come from a file extension. The only way to find out for sure what type of file a URL points to is to go ahead and fetch it (with an HTTP GET or HEAD request).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. The only problem is that I am trying to extract the links from a string, not a web page -- can I still use an HTML parser?

Comment: Yes, that's what `loadHTML()` does. It doesn't care whether the string was fetched from the network or not.