# how to take web page thumbnail on webpage via jquery + php of a link

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

How to take web page thumbnail on webpage via jquery + php of a link?

Suppose I pass a php variable

```
$screen="http://www.yahoo.com"
```

it use ajax/jquery/php to show the given URL thumbnail on page.

Comment: It's impossible to do without the help of server side programming.

Comment: yes i want to use PHP as a server side language as im on linux hosting? any idea? jquery to just populate it.

Comment: There are various solutions, check out http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+screenshot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any available PHP script that can grab a screenshot of the url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658159/are-there-any-available-php-script-that-can-grab-a-screenshot-of-the-url)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=web+site+screenshot

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of these ones and their api:
[Search block of text, return MP3 links using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514520/search-block-of-text-return-mp3-links-using-php)